# Error in my usage of fscanf with character class

Tags: c, scanf

I have a text file which has first line as below:

```
                    j0W82LBrSdUbw
```

Basically it can have many space,horizontal tabs in beginning then some characters having numbers or alphabets(width of this is 14 characters - fixed), and then some more space or tabs could be present. The width of the whole line is not known, i mean it could have any number of spaces or tabs in it. I want to neglect the leading and trailing white space but only take the letters/numbers into a string.

I tried to read it using fscanf with character class as shown below(I tried couple of ways but without success), but result is incorrect, it is not reading and ignoring the space , nor the actual letters are read. For test purpose I fixed the whole length of line to 54 characters in all(white spaces, numbers characters all included)

```
fscanf(fin,"%54*[ ]%[^ ]%*[ ]",s);//s is char array char s[100];
```

and

```
  fscanf(fin,"%54[^ \t]",s);
```

1] How do I parse this using fscanf when width of line is fixed and known say 54 characters.

2]When width of line is unknown and variable?

3]Where can I read a good documentation about using character classes in scanf/fscanf?

Comment: Won't a simple `fscanf(fin, "%14s", s);` work? The `"%s"` conversion specifier strips leading whitespace. Also note that your example has 13 visible characters, not 14.

Comment: `scanf/fscanf` are bad choices for parsing textual data. You're better off with `fgets` and `sscanf`; or maybe even better with `fgetc`. I suggest you stop looking for ways to parse your files with the `scan` family of functions.

Comment: There's nothing very special about the `"%["` `scanf` conversion specifier (it is not a regular expression, just a bunch of characters). It matches (or doesn't match if the 1st character is `'^'`) all of the following characters (with some extra rules for `']'`; and, in some implementations, `'-'`). See any [manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) for the details: I like [OpenGroup's manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fgetc()` in a loop. You may need to add error checking and treatment of borderline cases.

```
char s[15];
size_t sndx = 0;
int ch;
while (((ch = fgetc(fin)) != '\n') && (ch != EOF) && (sndx < 15)) {
    if (sndx || !isspace((unsigned char)ch)) {
        s[sndx++] = ch;
    }
}
s[sndx] = 0;
/* discard rest of line */
while (((ch = fgetc(fin)) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) /* void */;
```

Comment: thanks. a simple fscanf(fin,"%14s",s); worked. I did not knew that %s ingnores leading white space as well(I only knew it stops reading at a white space!)

Comment: any pointers about some articles to read about the behaviour of scanf character class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `[...]` construct here. It matches a *nonempty* sequence of characters.

Just use a simple `"%s"` format, it will ignore blank characters for you automatically. For added security, use `"%14s"`, so that an invalid input string won't owerflow your buffer.